# different categories of false file path java

Tags: java, file, path

i am making a program where I would read the data from excel file and store them in mysql database. In this program user would give the path of the file that would use. The code for doing so is the below.

```
 String strfullPath = "";
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in );
 System.out.println("Please enter the fullpath of the file");
 strfullPath = scanner.nextLine();
 String file = strfullPath.substring(strfullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 System.out.println(file.substring(0, file.indexOf('.')));
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 String filename = strfullPath.substring(strfullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
 System.out.println(filename);
 String[] parts = filename.split("\\.");
```

Then I would like the user when he gives the full path in the console to have the options of making a mistake. For example if he write a file that there is not in the folder or if he write special caracter that are not recognized or for example if he write the path in a not appropriate way. How I would give these command in java? How the user understand that something that he type is wrong?

Comment: What is exactly your question ?

Comment: There is no automatic way to diagnose the exact reason why a certain filesystem path is invalid. You'll have to write code for each special case you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

You should make a validation loop:

```
while (true)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the fullpath of the file:");
    strfullPath = scanner.nextLine();
    File f = new File(strfullPath );
    if (f.canRead()) break;
    System.out.println("Error: File does not exist");
}
```

**Edit**
This method checks if a path is valid and tries to correct it:

```
public static final String correctPath(final String path) {
    try {
        final String returnValue = new File(path).toPath().toAbsolutePath().normalize().toFile().toString();
        System.out.println(returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    } catch (final InvalidPathException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        final int errorIndex = e.getIndex();
        final String newPath = path.substring(0, errorIndex - 1) + path.substring(errorIndex + 1);
        return correctPath(newPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but how I would then specify if the user when he gives the path had editorial error? For example character as: /,," which are not recognisable?

Comment: The loop would continue and asks him for a valid path. I made an edit to clear this out.

Comment: Yes, but this is one possible error where the file does not exist. If the file that the user insert actually exist but the user does not give the right path? Foe example instead of writing: C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\testing.xls, he is writing C:.\Users.myuser.\Documents.\testing.xls how we would say that the structure of the given path is wrong?